# I receive an UnboundLocalError for 'num' and I don't know why

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to create a game and I get this error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment when I get past the first window, although I have already set num to be a global variable. I had the idea to just carry it through with my functions but tkinter doesn't allow me to do that and gives me an error.

```
 from tkinter import *

 global num
 num = 1.0



 def situation_1_1():
    if num == 1.0:
       window10.destroy()
       num = 1.1


   global window11
   window11 = Tk()
   window11.title( " " )
   window11.resizable( 0, 0 )

   img1 = PhotoImage( file = "img_1_0.png" )



   Img_1 = Label( window11, image = img1)

   Label_1 = Label( window11, relief = "groove", width = 50 )

   Btn_1 = Button( window11, text = "Look around", command = situation_1_1)
   Btn_2 = Button( window11, text = "Go out front", command = situation_1_2)



   Img_1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, rowspan = 75, columnspan = 75 )

   Label_1.grid( row = 1, column = 76, rowspan = 50, columnspan = 100, padx = ( 10, 10 ) )

   Btn_1.grid( row = 61, column = 76, columnspan = 50 )
   Btn_2.grid( row = 61, column = 126, columnspan = 50 )



   Label_1.configure( text = """ """ )

   window11.mainloop()



def situation_1_0(num):
   num = 1.0
   global window10
   window10 = Tk()
   window10.title( " " )
   window10.resizable( 0, 0 )

   img1 = PhotoImage( file = "img_1_0.png" )



   Img_1 = Label( window10, image = img1)

   Label_1 = Label( window10, relief = "groove", width = 50 )

   Btn_1 = Button( window10, text = "Explore the house", command = situation_1_1)
   Btn_2 = Button( window10, text = "Go round back", command = situation_1_2)



   Img_1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, rowspan = 75, columnspan = 75 )

   Label_1.grid( row = 1, column = 76, rowspan = 50, columnspan = 100, padx = ( 10, 10 ) )

   Btn_1.grid( row = 61, column = 76, columnspan = 50 )
   Btn_2.grid( row = 61, column = 126, columnspan = 50 )


   Label_1.configure( text = """ """)

   window10.mainloop()


situation_1_0(num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to assign a new value to a variable in an outer scope you need to add global keyword within your function.

In above example when you pass num to situation_1_0(..) function, num will be considered as local variable. Within the situation_1_0() you have defined a call to another function situation_1_1() which tries to assign a new value to global variable and hence you get an error: `local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`. Using global variable inside a function situation_1_1() should resolve your error

you can check the same with below sample example:

```
global num
num = 1.0

def bar():
    print(locals())
    global num
    if num == 1.0:
        num = 1.4
        print('num value withing bar fn: ', num)
# function to perform addition 
def foo(num):
    print(locals())
    bar()    
    print('num value within foo fn: ', num) 

# calling a function 
foo(num)
print('global num value: ', num)
```

locals() & globals() dictionaries can help to view what are variables are present